# Endless loop of installs in cygwin to get mysql

Tags: mysql, package, cygwin

I'm running windows 10.  I am evaluating software that was written in cygwin / mysql / python.
I installed cygwin from the mirrors.cs.vt.edu site.  According the setup program mysql is installed.
When I try to run mysql I get "-bash: mysql: command not found"
I found a note on stackoverflow that says "OH, just use apt-cyg", but when I do that it says
"-bash: apt-cyg: command not found"
Another note said "Oh, use lynx to install apt-cyg", but it can't find that either.
Dear god, can someone please explain what I have to install?  Apparently, it's already in there someplace.

Also can't download and build package X, because it can't find gcc either.
The only that works are ls, pwd, find, python, a few other things.

Comment: What is the output of `cygcheck -c mysql` ? The standard tool of installation of any Cygwin program is its setup. apt-cyg is not supported by the Cygwin team and it is known to have deficiencies. Please also note that Cygwin has thousands of packages https://cygwin.com/packages/package_list.html and by defaults only the base ones are installed ( around 50) if you need other programs you need to select them running again the `setup` and explicitly selecting them

Comment: Thanks for response.  I was finally able to install mysql from the cygwin installation tool.  (the selection had been greyed out previously).  I decided to install the windows version and have begun working with that. This questions is OBE.  I'm not sure if the appropriate thing is to delete it or leave it stand.